# CURL PHP Post request to download PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, curl, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have a form like the one below.

I want to download pdf file using php, I have some experience with CURL, but I can't get it to work. How should CURL request look like and how do I download the file once the request is made?

```
<form action="https://ems.ms.gov.pl/krs/danepodmiotu.form" method="post" >
    <input value="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" name="t:formdata" type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="t:submit" value="pobierzWydruk">
    <input value="DOWNLOAD" name="DOWNLOAD" type="submit">
</form>
```

This is what I tried, but CURL returns false.

```
    $url = 'https://ems.ms.gov.pl/krs/danepodmiotu.form';
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        't:submit' => 'pobierzWydruk',
        't:formdata' => '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');
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: When I submit the form code you provided, a download doesn't begin for me, and instead I get a web page. Is this the expected behavior? Is a PDF download supposed to begin?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Im looking for a way to download it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some basic steps that will help you re-build any request(for the most part) using cURL.

1. Open up the network tab in your browser's web inspector.
2. Perform the request in question.  Do whatever is needed to trigger the PDF download in your case.
3. Right click the request that triggered the download, in the network tab, and select `copy as cURL`.
4. Paste this into a text editor and start rebuilding the request using PHPs cURL bindings.

The pasted text will be the command line version of the `curl` command.  You can find out what each command option means [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).